# Connection to network broken

Tags: networking

I have a Chromebook and a Ubuntu 20.04 on my home network.  I setup the file sharing 3 years ago, works just fine.  Then I changed my CB password, which killed the sharing. I cannot figure out how to proceed; cannot delete the previous entry from the files app, can't reconnect to server (I can't remember what form of URL I used 3 years ago, but tried them all to no avail), don't know how to change the password on the Ubuntu side (tried to use passwd, but failed).

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on to the answer myself.  Go to Settings, then Online Accounts. My Google Cloud account is listed, click and proceed normally.  The Files app connection sequence is a total red herring and led me astray.